# Cloning a git repository to my own repository

Tags: git, github

Hi have a git repository shared by others `other/gitrepo` on github, I want to clone it to my own repo `myown/gitrepo` on github (with all information like commits, issues intact), what's the fastest way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean `git fork`?

Comment: https://www.toolsqa.com/git/git-fork/

Answer (score 0):

You want to [Fork a repo](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo).

> Most commonly, forks are used to either propose changes to someone else's project to which you do not have write access, or to use someone else's project as a starting point for your own idea. You can fork a repository to create a copy of the repository and make changes without affecting the upstream repository. For more information, see "[Working with forks.](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/working-with-forks)"